# Replace words returned from “Google Analytics Embed”

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to replace the returned Google Analytics Embed words?

I am using a function but it does not replace.

It's possible?

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjLrO.jpg)

```
function recursiveTranslate(e) {
var key = e.html(),
dict = {};

dict['Users'] = 'Usuários';

if (key in dict) {
e.html(dict[key]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < e.children().length; i++) {
recursiveTranslate($(e.children()[i]));
}
}

dataChart5.on('success', function h(obj) {
recursiveTranslate($('#chart-5-container'));
});
```